# Views filter that alternates content types?

Tags: 8, views

Does anyone know if it's possible to have a view that alternates between content types? Aka show 1 of content type news and then 1 of content type article repeating?

Answer (score 0):

Not automatically. You could custom code such a solution, maybe an advanced Pager for showing different number of results for each CT.

The usual way to solve this problem is to create different Attachment or Block Displays, each for a different Content Type, show them in the same Region and adjust the CSS styles to make them look like they are part of the same "box".